# Can't use keyboard shortcuts to switch spaces unless I'm in mission control

Tags: keyboard, spaces, mission-control

I have my Mac set up to switch spaces using `Cmd + Num` but sometimes, out of the blue, they will stop working unless I do the command when in mission control. Anybody have any idea why this happens?

Comment: something else is using that key combo? Lots of apps use Cmd/num to switch views; it's not a great one to have swapped it to, tbh.

Comment: It's odd, I use it without problem and it just seems to stop working at one point and not to anything at all.

Comment: Try Ctrl/num instead & see how it goes. I've used that since Spaces was invented & never had a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that some mission control problems are resolved by restarting the "Dock" process (which handles the job of Mission Control).  If you care to try that, the Terminal command is:

**killall Dock**

(But first use **killall -s Dock** to make sure the command will only kill the one process.)